# unrefactor storyboards in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a big storyboard in xcode and by mistake I have refactored some of my view controllers into a new storyboard. Is it possible to unrefector those view controllers to the original storyboard? I can't undo cause it doesn't work.

I have searched around but it seemed nothing is available. Or it is not possible?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Xcode doesn't have a **unrefactor** function from what i know.

However, you can actually just mouse drag over all the `ViewControllers` in your new `storyboard` and just copy paste it back to your original `storyboard`. The `segue` from one `ViewController` to another should still remain.

The only extra step you have to do is - manually revert the `segue` from pointing to new `storyboard` to the correct `ViewController`.